# MSBuild execution fails through jenkins whereas same command runs properly through command prompt

Tags: batch-file, jenkins, cmd, msbuild

I tried to execute the below command from Jenkins, and I got below error. I tried to print the command and executed the same command through cmd.exe and it runs successfully. I checked the folder permission and it is having the write permission. I ran jenkins using war file and saw it is executing under the same user as cmd.exe is running

Command that is executed on both jenkins and cmd.exe is,

"C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\12.0\Bin\MSBuild.exe" "d:\jenkins\workspace\NewTestItem\App\abc.sln" /t:rebuild /p:PackageLocation=d:\jenkins\workspace\NewTestItem\iisPackageDeploymentDir\26\ /p:DeployOnBuild=True /p:Configuration=Release /m /v:d /fl /flp:LogFile=msbuild.log;Verbosity=Normal  /nr:false

Error which I am getting in jenkins

Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(3821,5): error MSB3021: Unable to copy file "d:\jenkins\workspace\NewTestItem\App\mgmt\UserGuide\US\help.pdf" to "bin\mgmt\UserGuide\US\help.pdf". Access to the path 'bin\mgmt\UserGuide\US\help.pdf' is denied.

Note : Solution contains multiple project

Comment: Tgis looks like a relative path. Do you execute the build from the right directory? You might need to cd into it before executimg the msbuild.

Comment: or better, pass the full path to that destination directory (I've seen way to many bugs caused by relying on current working directory)

Comment: I used the echo statement to see what exact command is fired , I have used the absolute path

Comment: Hi Folks, I see the same issue today. can you share the fix ?